# python collectstatic commad is not ran in Docker compose and gitlab

Tags: django, docker, gitlab-ci

I am trying to run `python manage.py collectstatic` , in docker but nothing works, my python project misses some icons, and this command will solve the issue, but I can't know where to place the command, I have read several questions here but no luck.

Below is my `docker-compose.ci.stag.yml` file:

version: "3.7"

```
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.staging
      cache_from:
        - gingregisr*ty.azurecr.io/guio-tag:tag
    image: gingregisrty.azurecr.io/guio-tag:tag
    expose:
      - 7000
    env_file: .env
```

Then my `docker-compose.staging.yml` file :

```
version: '3.5'
# sudo docker login -p <password> -u <username>
services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    image: gingregisrty.azurecr.io/guio-tag:tag
    ports:
      - 7000:7000
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - app-network
  
  watchtower:
    image: containrrr/watchtower
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /root/.docker/config.json:/config.json
    command: --interval 30
    environment: 
      - WATCHTOWER_CLEANUP=true
    networks:
      - app-network

  nginx-proxy:
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:0.9
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 90:90
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    depends_on:
      - api
    networks:
      - app-network

  nginx-proxy-letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    env_file:
      - .env.prod.proxy-companion
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - acme:/etc/acme.sh
    depends_on:
      - nginx-proxy
    networks:
      - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  certs:
  html:
  vhost:
  acme:
```

then my `Docker.staging` file :

```
# ./django-docker/app/Dockerfile
FROM python:3.7.5-buster

# set work directory
WORKDIR /opt/app

# Add current directory code to working directory
ADD . /opt/app/

# set environment variables

# Prevents Python from writing pyc files to disc.
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
# Prevents Python from buffering stdout and stderr.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Copy firebase file
# COPY afro-mobile-test-firebase-adminsdk-cspoa.json

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    tzdata \
    python3-setuptools \
    python3-pip \
    python3-dev \
    python3-venv \
    git \
    && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install environment dependencies
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

# Install project dependencies
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 7000

# copy project
COPY . /opt/app/


CMD ["bash", "start-app.sh"]
```

then my `start-app.sh` file :

```
#Run migrations
python manage.py migrate

#run tests
# python manage.py test

# run collect statics
python manage.py collectstatic

echo 'COLLECT STAIIC DONE ********'
 
echo $PORT
# Start server
# python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:$PORT
gunicorn server.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

Am using gitlab ci to automate the pipeline, so here is my `gitlab.yml` build script:

```
# Build and Deploy to Azure.
build-dev:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - export IMAGE=$CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE/$CI_PROJECT_NAME
  script:
    - apk add --no-cache bash
    - chmod +x ./setup_env.sh
    - bash ./setup_env.sh
    - docker login $AZ_REGISTRY_IMAGE -u $AZ_USERNAME_REGISTRY -p $AZ_PASSWORD_REGISTRY
    - docker pull $AZ_REGISTRY_IMAGE/guio-tag:tag || true
    - docker-compose -f docker-compose.ci.stag.yml build
    - docker push $AZ_REGISTRY_IMAGE/guio-tag:tag
  only:
    - develop
    - test-branch
```

The build runs successfully, but am sure `python manage.py collectstatic` is not ran, how best can I do this ?

Comment: Are your static assets supposed to be served by `gunicorn` or `nginx`? Can you post your `settings.py` and also `nginx.conf` if relevant?

Comment: your collect static wont be run in the build process, you have defined it in your start script which is the default command to the container. It wont exist in the container image, it will be executed when the container is started.

Comment: @Selcuk, here is the link to my [settings.py](https://gist.github.com/huxaiphaer/ed96f8aa876cf99d0e1f683eeca07e70)

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, so why is the `python manage.py collectstatic` not working then if it's executed ?

Comment: I did more digging and commented out this line `gunicorn server.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT` , and redeployed, the application is running well, seems `start-app.sh` Is not ran @ChrisDoyle